# Push notifications server side datamodel

Tags: ios, database-design, webserver, push-notification

I'm creating a C# .NET webserver application that will notify iOS users when an HTML page they're interested in has new data.  I'd like to give the users the ability to be notified via email and/or push notifications.  Here is what I have so far for the "Users" table in a SQL Server database:

**userID** (unique int value)
**deviceToken** (unique varchar value provided by apple when setting up a new notification)
**isActive** (bool)
**createDate** (date/time record was created)

Are there any other fields you think are necessary?  I've researched the Parse push notifications service, but I'm not sure how I would implement it or why it would be easier then sending the push notifications myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also want to add environment field (to distinguish sandbox and prod environment).
If you are planning on extending to support Android C2DM, you may want to create a "zone" field, that would identify client type (method of notification delivery).

If you need to limit number of notifications sent to user, timestamp of last notification sent to given device may be a good idea.